# Boolean Input and Output Issue

Tags: python, input, boolean

```
x = bool(input())
print(x)
```

Input: False
Output: True
Why is the output always `True` irrespective of the input?

Comment: Would you expect `bool('wrong')` to be `False`…?

Comment: `input()` gives string `"False"` and `bool(not_empty_string)` gives `True` - `bool()` doesn't check what text you have in this string.